# Mysql string is being rejected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a new sql string, but it is far more complex than anything I wrote before and I'm fairly certain it wrong somewhere

```
SELECT manga.mangaName,chapter.chapterNumber,chapter.chapterName,
chapter.chapterID,counter.dateUpdated,
DATE_FORMAT(chapter.dateUploaded,'%b %D %Y') as dateUploaded,
pageViews.counter
FROM manga, chapter, pageViews
WHERE manga.mangaID = chapter.mangaID AND chapter.chapterID = pageViews.chapterID
AND counter.dateUpdated BETWEEN ".$Monday." AND ".$Sunday."
ORDER BY pageViews.counter DESC LIMIT 1";
```

that is the warning that comes along with it

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homez.380/mangasma/www/index.php on line 39

Comment: Are you getting a mysql error or is the issue that you aren't getting any results?

Comment: Can you generate and echo the actual string (without the variables Monday and Sunday so we can see the REAL query that is failing?

Comment: It would probably help to see the error message that MySQL is giving you.

Answer (score 3):

You are including the table `counter` in your `SELECT` but not in your `FROM`. That could be part of the problem.

Comment: +1.  It's in the `WHERE` clause, but you win.

Comment: I meant to put pageViews instead of counter, but still hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: Well your new information shows us that it's a PHP error, not a MySQL error, so it looks like you may be using the sql query-resource relationship incorrectly. Can we see the lines of code after this, leading up to the mysql_fetch_array() line 39?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax highlighting above.  You seem to have an extra double-quote (") at the end.

Edit: @thegreasyitalian has something too.

Comment: I think that that's part of the PHP script and not something that goes to MySQL.

Comment: That makes the earlier double-quotes make a lot more sense.  Too much bouncing between languages.  I keep forgetting that SQL doesn't do much with double-quotes.  I think HTML/JSP has corrupted me into assuming they are interchangeable with single-quotes.

Comment: Grr.  I hate that I can't comment on others yet.  The SQL above still has counter.dateUpdated in it.

Comment: Yeah he hasn't changed it yet, nor updated it with more complete PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The php variables in the SQL string were missing a set of quotation marks